# Passing variable into lambda

Tags: c++, pointers, lambda

I have a function that takes as an argument `CallbackType`, which is

```
typedef (*void) (const *char, bool)
```

I need to pass additional context, so I thought it would be a good idea to use lambdas:

```
CallbackType DelegateHandler(Pointer ptr) {
    return [&](const char* a, bool b) {
        callback(ptr, a, b); 
    };
}
```

It only works though if it's a capturing lambda, and a capturing lambda cannot be converted to a regular function pointer, so I get the error:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from SetHandler(Pointer)::<lambda(const char*, bool)>’ to ‘CallbackType’ {aka ‘void(*)(const char*, bool)’
```

Any idea how to solve this in a simple fashion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-capturing-lambda-as-function-pointer

Comment: Can you share the code link here in comment with some online compiler?
It would be helpful to debug

Comment: Use templates? std::function?

Answer (score 3):

As [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56027704/2018010) already pointed out, closures can not be converted to function pointers.

It might be better to accept templated argument or [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of raw function pointer, if there is such an option.

Comment: @Mayur, without OP's code (part that accepts and calls callback) it would be a guess game.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda functions that contain captures are not convertible to normal function pointers.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220658/what-is-the-difference-between-a-closure-and-a-lambda) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-capturing-lambda-as-function-pointer) SO question for more.

Generally, you have a callback that allows you to include a custom pointer which is passed, which will contain the extra data you want from the callback.