# Why memory usage is bigger for closures

Tags: php

I realized, that closures are consuming more memory. Could someone help me to understand why it is happening like that, please? Also, having following results, is it not recommended to use closures?

```php
$value = 10;
$memory = memory_get_usage();

$fun = static function ($add, $value) {
    $value += $add;

    echo $value;
};

$fun(10, $value);

echo ' | ' . $value . ' | memory: ' . (memory_get_usage() - $memory);
```

Output:

> 20 | 10 | memory: 368

```php
$value = 10;
$memory = memory_get_usage();

$closure = static function (int $add) use ($value) {
    $value += $add;

    echo $value;
};

$closure(10);

echo ' | ' . $value . ' | memory: ' . (memory_get_usage() - $memory);
```

Output:

> 20 | 10 | memory: 752

(the same is happening for objects)

Comment: You'd better ask the PHP developers... maybe has to do with the way how the second parameter is injected. Btw: both examples are closures...

Comment: @LarsStegelitz
Isn't that the 1st one is an anonymous function and 2nd is a closure? If not, then I don't fully understand what is a closure then :/.

Comment: a closure IS an anonymous function... it's just another term. https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Hmm... so I'm confused. Was reading other articles as this which was describing that those are different things: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220658/what-is-the-difference-between-a-closure-and-a-lambda, and an example quote: "Not all closures are lambdas and not all lambdas are closures."

Comment: @UrmatZhenaliev Isn't that functions assigned to a variable are lambdas (anonymous functions)? They do not have a name as they're just assigned to a variable. I'm confused even more, so I'm asking :).

Comment: The terms "closure" and "anonymous function" are often used for the same thing. Strictly speaking they are not the same. A closure is the combination of a function and its environment. In this case the "use" keyword defines a variable in that environment, which is not visible outside of it. OTOH, you could argue that the first example is a closure as well, just with an empty environment. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 1):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/10304027/7265862:

> 4. ***use*** is early binding. That means the variable values are COPIED upon DEFINING the closure. So modifying `$tax` inside the
>    closure has no external effect, unless it is a pointer, like an object
>    is.

It means, that in your second example you actually **copied** `$value`. While in first example you pass the pointer to `$add` and `$value`. Therefore, your script consumed more memory in second function

> is it not recommended to use closures?

I guess it's opinion and task based question. Most of developers prefer clean code rather few bytes. But some projects work under a very high load, thus managers demand to save every byte.

In my projects, I try to maintain the most concise, readable and maintainable code. So, I would prefer `lambdas`, rather `closures`. Not because of optimization, but to make my function independent from out of scope variables.

And to optimize the project using other means: cache, database, architecture. Because trying to save those measly few bytes, you can frustrate the whole project.

Comment: This cannot explain why the memory usage is doubled, a pointer copy doesn't need about 400 bytes.