# Using scala to accumulate elementwise sums

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Scala, how do I fold a List and return the intermediate results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224935/in-scala-how-do-i-fold-a-list-and-return-the-intermediate-results)

I am searching for a functional way of accumulating the elements of a SortedTree in the following way:

I want a list with containing the sums of all precursors (including the element itself) for all elements in the SortedTree.

For Exmaple:

SortedTree contains (0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05)

I want the list: (0,4. 0.7, 0. 9, 1, 1.05)

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Tomasz thank you. didn't found that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no `SortedTree` in the standard library, but you just want `scanLeft` (assuming your type extends [`TraversableLike`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableLike)):

```
seq.scanLeft(0.0)(_ + _).tail
```

or if you want a list:

```
seq.toList.scanLeft(0.0)(_ + _).tail
```

Comment: More like scanLeft than reduceLeft, as the intermediate sums are required

Comment: Yes, already fixed. For some reason I thought for a moment `reduceLeft` worked like `scanLeft` starting with first element instead of `foldLeft` starting with first element.

Comment: Sounds like a good addition to the library, maybe call it `seduceLeft`?