# Why is there a compile error in this code?

Tags: c, closures, function-pointers

I was trying to understand the difference between closures and function pointers, and I came across [this answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208835/function-pointers-closures-and-lambda/208940#208940)

What I don't understand is this code

```
BOOL (*lessThanTest)(int);
int lessThan = 100;

lessThanTest = &LessThan;

BOOL LessThan(int i) {
   return i < lessThan; // compile error - lessThan is not in scope
}
```

Why there is a compile error consideringn that lessThan is a global variable, it can be accessed from within LessThan function, did I miss something?

**EDIT**

This is not my code, it's taken from an answer in SO [Function pointers, Closures, and Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208835/function-pointers-closures-and-lambda/208940#208940)

Comment: can you post minimum compilable code? (comment out the part that gives you the error)

Comment: That wouldn't even compile, since `LessThan` isn't yet declared before `lessThanTest = &LessThan;`

Comment: This is invalid code in C. You can achieve same result as in c# using c++ and functors.

Comment: @neagoegab -- it's not supposed to be valid C and it's not his example.  Read the linked question for more context.

Comment: But it is still a bad example with incomplete specifications... Closure can have state same as a functor while a function pointer does not have a state and the state is maintained in a global variable or passed as an argument....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a paragraph in that answer:

> But, now I have to pass the 2 arguments when I evaluate it. If I wished to pass this function pointer to another function **where lessThan was not in scope**, I would either have to manually keep it alive by passing it to each function in the chain, **or by promoting it to a global**.

In what you posted, `int lessThan` is not meant at global scope, it should be assumed to be in a function somewhere.

Comment: I think that paragraph is talking about the second code snippet

Comment: (I think) It talks about both. Neither are strictly valid `C` at global scope anyway.

Comment: "I could define a function pointer " ... "If I wished to pass **this** function pointer "

Comment: I don't see your point. If `lessThan` was at global scope, there would be no compiler error (assuming the rest of the code was correct). Both examples manipulate a function pointer, the second one has different object lifetime/visibility issues than the first, but both have the same fundamental problem - C doesn't have closures (or lambdas, or nested functions for that matter), you need to implement workarounds yourself.

Comment: my point is, what can be done in closures can be done using functions pointers with some workarounds like you said

Comment: Then what is your question? The code you quoted isn't valid at global scope, and you understand stuff needs to be done to simulate closures.

Comment: My question is about that snippet of code, for what reason did the author say it's a compile error, while it can work if lessThan variable is a global variable

Comment: It's a compiler error if `lessThan` is not in scope in the `LessThan` function. Since C doesn't have nested functions (or classes), the only ways for `lessThan` to be in scope are 1. global, 2. argument.

Answer (score 2):

Closures take all the variables in their lexical scope along for the ride, possibly extending their lifetimes.  Function pointers don't -- if the variables referenced inside their code disappear, they're hosed.

The code example you've given is a little bit confusing.  I believe that it's meant to be inside of a function, meaning that `lessThan` is a local variable.  If that scope is exited, but the function pointer still exists, then its code would have a reference to a non-existent variable -- `lessThan`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no, if `lessThan` is global, it shouldn't produce compile error, though you can hardly tell by this fragment what is meant to be where. `lessThanTest=&LessThan;` is definitely from some local scope, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

This code has some problems:

- You declare `lessThanTest` as an uninitialized function pointer
- You can't assign something to it later under global scope
- You're using `LessThan` before declaring it.