# What's the difference between lambda expressions and function pointers?

Tags: lambda, function-pointers

I've been researching lambda expressions recently and to me they seem like your average function pointer but I might be missing something, can someone please explain the difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208835/function-pointers-closures-and-lambda

Comment: How did I not find that?! Thanks