# Give non-declared function to function pointer

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

I am trying to understand all this HUGE concept of function pointers...

Is it possible to initalize function pointer with non-declared function?

For example, a simple use of function pointer would be:

```
void f()
{
  printf("Hello world!");
}
//Somewhere in the program
void (*foo)();
foo = &f;
```

Is there any way to skip the declaration of f? something like that:

```
void (*foo)();
foo = { printf("Hello world!"); }
```

Comment: In `C`, no. `C++` has the concept of lambdas that fit what you're trying to do.

Comment: In C, you need to make it a named function (probably a `static` one, unless you intend to reuse it from other compilation units) .

Comment: In C (as well as C++) you haved to declare a name before using it.

Comment: Short answer: C no, C++ yes.

Comment: C# also supports this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe are called [lambda functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function), a mechanism which is not available in C. You can think of lambda functions as anonymous functions.

C++ and C# support that. Read more in .[Function pointers, Closures, and Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208835/function-pointers-closures-and-lambda)