# Where the nested function's body kept?

Tags: c, linux, function, storage-class-specifier, data-segment

Please check the following code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void* make_adder_function(int a)
{

    char str[64] ={};

    sprintf(str,"this function adds %d with input",a);

    void adder(int b) {
        int x = a;
        char ptr[64] = {};
        strcpy(ptr,str);
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", x, b, x+b);
    }

    return adder;
}


int main()
{
    void (*adder_ten)(int);
    void (*adder_twenty)(int);

    adder_ten = make_adder_function(10);
    adder_twenty = make_adder_function(20);

    adder_ten(20);
    adder_twenty(20);

    return 0;
}
```

While Running the code I am getting the following output,

```
ajith@chat:~/Desktop$ ./a.out 
this function adds 20 with input
20 + 20 = 40
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It shows like the scope of `function adder()` is only inside the `make_adder_function()`, I assumes this happens because the function body of `adder()` is kept in the stack frame of `make_adder_function()`. Can anybody give an explanation for this? How can I persist a nested function's lifetime throughout the program?

Comment: Nested functions are non-standard in C.

Comment: C doesn't have nested functions. Nested functions is a non-portable compiler-specific extension of GCC. Please avoid such extensions.

Comment: The problem is not the function, the problem is the `printf("%s\n", str);`, where `str` refers to a buffer that has reached its lifetime. The local variable `a`, that you use, also, btw, but it doesn't lead to a crash. It can contain some arbitrary value, however.

Comment: Please to not make changes to your code after receiving comments and answers. Your changes make them useless.

Comment: [Info on how to correctly emulate a closure in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/345881/3386109). Summary: it's a pita.

Comment: @user3386109 making a closure in C is trivial -- provided that you don't want to pass it as an argument to a function which expect a simple function pointer as argument.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem (the non-standard extension aside) is that the local variable `str` inside the `make_adder_function` function will have ended its life-time when the `make_adder_function` function ends. And this happens before you call the `adder` function, which then tries to use the non-existing `str` variable.

The nested-function extension only nests functions, it doesn't have [*closures*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

As a simple workaround you could make `str` a `static` variable. Its life-time would then be for the full runtime of the program. The problem then is that there's only *one* variable, which will be shared between all calls to the `make_adder_function` function.

Comment: now I added local variables for out of scope values

Comment: @AjithCNarayanan That doesn't change anything, you still use variables, that are past their lifetime, when you copy `str` and `a` inside `adder()`. And please do not make edits that invalidate existing answers, if you want to show current code, do it _below_ the original code marked with "Edit:" or similar.

Comment: @AjithCNarayanan Your change doesn't help, you still attempt to use `str` after its life-time. The copying you now do is done when `adder` is called, not when `make_adder_function` is called.